# Java Regex behaviour for Alternation (|) and + in a single expression

Tags: java, regex

Can some explain the following output for java regex:(CASE 1)

```
   String s = "topcoder is "

            String p = "(top|coder)+";
            Pattern pttrn = Pattern.compile(p);
            Matcher m = pttrn.matcher(s);
            while(m.find()){
                System.out.println("group count: " + m.groupCount());
                for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Found : \"" + m.group(i) + "\" as group " + i);
                }
                System.out.println("Zeroth group:" + m.group(0));
            }
```

produces following output:

group count: 1

Found : "coder" as group 1

Zeroth group:topcoder

Where the following code:  (CASE 2)

```
        String s = "topcoder is ";
        String p = "(top|coder)";
        Pattern pttrn = Pattern.compile(p);
        Matcher m = pttrn.matcher(s);
        while(m.find()){
            System.out.println("group count: " + m.groupCount());
            for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Found : \"" + m.group(i) + "\" as group " + i);
            }
            System.out.println("Zeroth group:" + m.group(0));
        }
```

produces following output:

group count: 1

Found : "top" as group 1

Zeroth group:top

group count: 1

Found : "coder" as group 1

Zeroth group:coder

Why isn't there are match for top in CASE 1 ? How is + affecting the matching for alternation (|) ?

Comment: When you repeat a capture group with a quantifier, the previous capture is overwritten by the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a capturing group that repeats, ie. because of a quantifier, the `Matcher` will only capture the last match.

You can wrap the entire repeated capturing group in its own capturing group to extract each match

```
String p = "((top|coder)+)";
```

This is explained in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uO1lQ1/1).